# CSS style is not being applied in aspx page?

Tags: css, asp.net

I placed following line in the head content of .aspx file:

```
< link href="/Theme/BaseStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen"/>
```

Following is the content of my BaseStyle.css:

```
.ButtonList .ContinueButton {width: 70px;}
```

And, following is my aspx markup:

```
< Telerik:RadButton ID="BackButton" runat="server"  Text="&lt; Back (Placeholder)" OnClick="BackButton_Click" ButtonType="LinkButton">
```

Do you see why the Width of **.ButtonList .ContinueButton** is not being applied ??
For your help, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

Specify the class name:

```
<Telerik:RadButton ID="BackButton" runat="server" Text="<Back (Placeholder)" 
OnClick="BackButton_Click" ButtonType="LinkButton" class="ButtonList">
```

.ButtonList matches all elements with class name = "ButtonList"

See these for more information:
http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/selectors
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I do have BlackButton class in Div.
I placed the teleric control in div section, something like

<div class="BackButton>
   Control....
</div>

Comment: Sorry about that BlackButton :D